# c#: programmatically create a "named range" in worksheet scope

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

How can we create a 'named range' that has its scope set to a *worksheet*? (as we can do this manually from Excel, I guess there is a way to this in code)

Setting a name using the '`Range.Name`' property creates a workbook-scoped named range. I tried prefixing the range name with '<Sheet Name>!' as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057189), but it doesn't work. The name doesn't get set at all that way.

Any idea as to how this can be done in C#?

Update (2013/05/16):
[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16568588/813976) by shahkalpesh worked. The original code (in VS 2010) I used is:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excel.Worksheet ws = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
Excel.Range range = ws.Range[ws.Cells[x,y], ws.Cells[(x + height), (y + width)]];
range.Name = "MyName"; // MyName in workbook scope
```

The modified code that works is:

```
ws.Names.Add("MyName", range); // MyName in worksheet scope
```

Thanks,
idssl.

Comment: Code please? How are you creating the named range?

Comment: I find recording Macro in Excel, then looking at the code it generates helps you find the code behind to do things in C# or whatever language you're looking for.

Comment: thanks a lot you saved my day

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assumptions:
Sheet1 has cells A1:A4, for which you want to create a named range

VBA:

```
Sheet1.Names.Add("tada", Sheet1.Range("A1:A4"))
```

I suppose it will be identical in c# (except the `;` at the end) and passing empty arguments for optional parameters.

Comment: Yeah it is something like shahkalpesh wrote, expcept he is missing the closing parentheses:
worksheet.Names.Add("MyRange", worksheet.Range("A1:A4"));

Comment: Another little "gotcha" is the scoping of named ranges. Add it to the workbook object using workbook.Names.Add(...) if you need to access it across other sheets.