# Set Named Range in an Excel Sheet using ACE.OLEDB and c#

Tags: c#, .net, vba, oledb, com-interop

I'm trying to import data from SQL database into an Excel file and then set a named range for the imported data. This is pretty straight forward using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel namespace as give [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568476/c-programmatically-create-a-named-range-in-worksheet-scope).  But the major drawback of this driver is that it expects Excel to be installed on the server machine. This is not an ideal situation for our use case. On the other hand, the ACE OLEDB driver operates with most of the excel versions and it doesn't expect Excel to be installed on the server. With the ACE driver, I searched a lot but couldn't find any convincing solution to set a named range in a sheet. I'm not very keen on using third party drivers. Anyone else with the same problem?

Comment: There is no solution in the ACE driver because it is not its job. Ranges are Excel objects strictly connected to the Excel application domain, while the ACE driver is related to database functionality. Better look at thirdy party libraries like [EPP Plus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @Steve You are right about the ACE driver! Thanks