# Need to change multiple cell names in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple cell names already created in excel. I want to add prefix to each of these names based on what sheet they are in. I'm currently using this VBA code to do so:

```
  Sub RenameCells() Dim n As Name
  For Each n In Sheet1.Names
      n.Name = "NLOC1_" & n.Name
  Next n 
  End Sub
```

However, it does not seem to actually change the names in the sheet. I get no errors so I'm not sure what is wrong and why nothing is changing.

Comment: That is probably because the name is a workbook scope and not a worksheet scope.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057189/how-to-change-named-range-scope

Answer (score 1):

The names seem to be at Workbook level, so you need to use:

```
Sub RenameCells() Dim n As Name
  For Each n In ActiveWorkbook.Names
      n.Name = n.RefersToRange.Worksheet.Name & "_" & n.Name
  Next n 
End Sub
```